# OAuth token and custom errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

In my ASP.NET application I overrided `OAuth` `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` this way:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    using (var userManager = _userManagerFactory())
    {
         var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

         if (user == null)
         {
             context.Rejected();
             context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Invalid username or password");
             return;
         }
```

Token end-point:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
```

It works and I receive the error client side:

```
responseText: "{"error":"invalid_grant"...ame or password"}"
responseJSON: Object { error="invalid_grant",  error_description="Invalid username or password"}
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
```

Now, if I try to configure custom errors in `web.config` file:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <error statusCode="403" path="/Error/Unauthorized" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

I receive a `Bad Request` without the JSON message:

```
responseText:"Bad Request"
status  400
statusText:"Bad Request"
```

I think custom errors affects all requests and prevent the expected behavior.

I tried to add this in web.config:

```
<location path="Token">
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough">
      <clear />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

It works on my developer machine with `IIS Express` but `IIS 8.5` on production server seems to ignore it.

You can download the sample project from [here](http://www.olgiatidaniele.com/Public/TestTokenCustomErrors.zip). Just go to `Login` page and press login button. I've also commented `web.config` file.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: _"It works and I receive the error client side."_ Which error code and which JSON are you expecting?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal verifiable example?

Comment: Isn't this ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: I'll prepare a sample project. Yes I'm using asp.net identity.

Comment: Added a downloadable full example

Comment: Just a detail : SetError() internally call Rejected(). You can remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of research I finally get it to works.

I changed override configuration from:

```
<location path="Token">
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough">
      <clear />
    </httpErrors>

  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

to:

```
<location path="Token">
    <system.webServer>
       <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

       <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: The difference is that you were clearing httpErrors with <clear /> and now you aren't clearing them anymore. Sorry to hear you were stuck with that :) It happens... :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the existingResponse="PassThrough" in the configuration?

[Source:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690497(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I already have this configuration in overrided configuration:
 <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough">. The question is... why it doesn't works in IIS 8.5?